# How to publish an executable with dependencies only?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to create an executable that is framework dependent and will only run on Win x64.

To that end, I execute `dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64`.  I am expecting only my exe, dll and direct dependencies.

Instead, the command generates `win10-x64` and `win10-x64\publish`.  The `win10-x64` folder only contains the app without any dependencies.  The `win10-x64\publish` has 236 files including a ton of api-ms-win-core-*.dll files which seem to be native, not managed.

So how do I generate an executable with direct dependencies only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dotnet publish [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21), take a look at what it says for the `--self-contained` parameter:

> Publishes the .NET Core runtime with your application so the runtime doesn't need to be installed on the target machine. If a runtime identifier is specified, its default value is true.

So since you are specifying a runtime identifier with the `-r` parameter, it is creating a self contained app by default. Try adding `--self-contained:false` to your command and see if that produces what you expect.